# Select múltiplo para evitar 2 consultas ao banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, select

Possuo o seguinte select (usando PDO):

```
$usuariosListados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_1, user_2 FROM usuarios WHERE user_1 = '".$_SESSION["usuario"]."' AND estatus = 2");
$usuariosListados -> execute();
$fAll = $usuariosListados -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rCount= $usuariosListados -> rowCount();


// E o seguinte foreach
if(rCount) {
    foreach($fAll as $itemUser) {
        echo "Usuário amigo: ".$itemUser["user_2"];
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
}
```

Porém, precisaria fazer outro select, mas da seguinte maneira:

```
$usuariosListados_2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_1, user_2 FROM usuarios WHERE user_2 = '".$_SESSION["usuario"]."' AND estatus = 2");
```

E o foreach seria:

```
foreach($fAll_2 as $itemUser_2) {
    echo "Usuário amigo: ".$itemUser["user_1"];
}
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de "juntar" esses selects assim evitando fazer 2 consultas ao banco de dados. Lembrando que, o `user_1` e o `user_2` nunca serão iguais, e eu preciso do valor que corresponde ao "contrário" do usuário logado (que é o `$_SESSION["usuario"]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer uma consulta assim:

```
"SELECT user_1, user_2 FROM usuarios 
WHERE '" . $_SESSION['usuario'] . "' IN ( user_1, user_2 ) " .
"AND estatus = 2"
```

Essa consulta devolve qualquer usuario que estja no `user_1` ou `user_2` que igual o `$_SESSION['usuario']`.

### Explicação

Se você está querendo ambos o `user_1` onde igual `$_SESSION['usuario']` e *também* o `user_2` onde igual `$_SESSION['usuario']`, a consulta em cima dá exatamente isso - ou seja:

> Consulto o user_1 e user_2 na tabela *usuarios* onde $_SESSION['usuario'] igual pelo menos um dos dois, e também ambas tenham o estatus de 2.

Aí, o seu `$usuariosListados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` vai conter duas (ou mais) resultados, sendo um do `user_1` e o outro de `user_2`.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? Ficou meio confuso.

Comment: Talvez eu não entendi seu desejo final -- essa constula apenas de dá os dois usuários de uma vez só (apenas uma consulta ao banco de dados). Depois disso, creio que não entendi seu propósito - mas espero que consegui responder a pergunta :|

Comment: (pelo que eu entendi e pesquisei) o `IN` serve para retornar os resultados que sejam iguais ao `WHERE`, mas eu preciso do diferente. Ou seja, se `user_1` for = a `$_SESSION["usuario"]` então, no foreach usarei o `user_2` e vice-versa. Há como fazer isso?

Comment: Consegui adaptar sua resposta ao meu problema fazendo apenas uma verificação if/else, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo!